# Redis: storing complex json

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, caching, redis

Thanks in advance for taking time to answer the question. I am new to Redis.

I have a complex JSON of the form

```
{
   key: {
            "key": val
            "a": {
                     "b": "c,
                     "d": {
                              "a1": "b1",
                               ...
                      },
                      ...
             },
             ...
    },
    ...
    ...
}
```

And this structure is formed from querying sources that are slow to respond. But I can have a background job building this structure and storing it in a cache somewhere that I can later retrieve. Is it possible to store a complex structure like this in Redis (I am using Ruby)? If not, what is the suggested approach to this problem.

Cheers.

Comment: Turn the JSON into a string, and just put that string in Redis.

Comment: Thanks, is this a standard approach (i.e., to convert something complex to a string and store)?

Comment: I'm not sure, you should do some more research. The other options are to put your key names as `user:5:name:first` or to use the hash datatype. But the first method is annoying and the hash data type doesn't support nested data.

Comment: you can either use JSON stringify like Stephen suggested or HASHES, but since you have more than one level, you'll have to eventually stringify the sub-JSON if you use HASHES anyway.